# Posicionar menu sobre imagem com CSS

Tags: css

Como deixar o menu fixo e sobre o *background* de imagem?

```
<hearder>
  <img src="imgs/principal.jpg" alt="estilo">
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Consultoria de imagem</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Outros Serviços</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <p>Valorize sua essencia, crie sua melhor versão!</p>
</hearder>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como na ordem do seu HTML a tag `<img>` vêm antes da tag `<nav>` naturalmente a Nav já fica por cima da imagem, não precisa de `z-index`. Já o menu vc pode fixar usando `position:fixed` ou `position:sticky`

Seque um exemplo com exatamente o seu HTML, apenas usei umas classes CSS para ficar melhor apresentado.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; 
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

header img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="estilo">
    <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Consultoria de imagem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Outros Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Valorize sua essencia, crie sua melhor versão!</p>
</header>

<div style="height:2000px; width:100px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed;` no css do seu menu, pode ser inline (na linha do código) ou externo (arquivo separado), segue o exemplo com o css inline:

```html
<header style="position: fixed;">
        <img src="imgs/principal.jpg" alt="estilo">
        <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Consultoria de imagem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Outros Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

agora se quiser fazer externo pode fazer assim:

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<header class="menu">
        <img src="imgs/principal.jpg" alt="estilo">
        <nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Consultoria de imagem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Outros Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Agora se você quer algo por cima de tudo, use no css `z-index: 9900;`, o z-index é ordem de prioridade, o maior número estará por cima. (é que na sua pergunta ficou `insira o código aqui`).

Bem é isso, qualquer coisa me avise!